# Массовая замена символов в строчке с помощью Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Подскажите, можно ли в Notepad++ с помощью **одного** рег. выражения или другим способом массово заменить символы в строчке? Например в строчке **jhgdfa7gdfailsdig90c8hgdjvfcdicur** заменить A->B, C->D, E->F и т.п. Главное, чтобы не нужно было для замены каждого символа делать отдельную операцию. Может быть, какой-то плагин для этого нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Все-таки можно заменить сразу несколько значений за одну операцию стандартными средствами в Notepad++ 6.0 и выше:

```
Find: (AAA)|(BBB)
Replace: (?1ZZZ)(?2XXX)
```